# How to preserve original indexing of string elements after using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to remove all letters and numbers from a string. For this I use the following regex methods:

```
txt = read_file()

pattern = r'[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyx0123456789]'
mod_string = re.sub(pattern, '', txt)
new_string = re.sub(r'\s+', '', mod_string)
for i in new_string:
    print(new_string.index(i), i)
```

The first use of the `re.sub()` method is for removing the letters and numbers, and the second is for removing the white spaces that remain.
However, when I want to access the indexes of the elements of the resulting string, it outputs the following (this is just a snippet of the real output, as that is much larger):

```
0 .
91 ]
92 <
92 <
57 -
1 ,
0 .
1 ,
0 .
99 (
100 )
1 ,
99 (
100 )
0 .
0 .
106 >
106 >
0 .
0 .
0 .
0 .
99 (
100 )
```

How can I achieve the same, but have a 'normal' indexing?
For example if I have a string with `">)(.>"`, if i want to get the indexes, it want `0: >`, `1: )`, `2: (`, `3: .`, `4: >` this is so that i can work with it easier after. I want to convert the string to a list of individual strings, which is why i need the indexes to be like this.

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of 'normal indexing' you mentioned? I want you to write your desirable output as well.

Comment: For example if I have a string with `"> ) ( . "`, if i want to get the indexes, it want `0: >` , `1: )`, `2: (`, `3: .` this is so that i can work with it easier after.

Comment: What if '>' appears twice, for example, "> ) ( . >"?

Comment: I want to convert it to a list of individual strings later, so that does not matter for me.

Comment: Laurens, when a reader asks for clarification it's always best to edit your question. Questions should be stand-alone, in the sense that readers should not be expected to read comments to understand the question.

Comment: Clarification is necessary. If the txt is `> ) ( . >`, which one is your desireble output, `0: >, 1: ), 2: (, 3: ., 4: >` or `0: >, 1: ), 2: (, 3: .`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean the second example. A character can show up more than once in the list later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```py
import re

txt = "ab>c)def(0123456    .> 789"

pat = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9 ]')
new_string = pat.sub('', txt) # new_string is ">)(.>" after pat.sub operation.

for i, s in enumerate(new_string): # Just show a pair of index and character in new_string
    print(i, s)
```

Comment: I updated my code with comment. See also this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: I don't want us to include multi-topics in a single question. Please open a new question if you cannot find docs.